# remove one single commit from history

Tags: git

I know it's anti-pattern but I have a LOCAL branch (and no other branch is based on this one) that is like that :

`D <-- C <-- B <-- A <-- HEAD`

I did it without testing and I need it to become like that

`D <-- C <-- A <-- HEAD` (I added some packages in B that I want to remove)

And later (if everything works correctly), I would like to make it :

`D <-- C <-- A <-- B <-- HEAD` so it would be great if I can keep the changes made in B to be able to choose if I want to re-apply them but later in the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git tag save-B B
git rebase --onto B~ B..
```

and then when you want `B` back you can cherry-pick `save-B` or merge it.

Answer (score 2):

1. `git rebase -i D` where D is the hash (commit-ish) of commit D.

   This opens your editor with a file containing a list of commits from D, for example

   ```
   pick A
   pick B
   pick C
   pick D
   ```
2. Remove or reorder the commits as desired, following the instructions provided in the comments at the bottom of the file, then save and close the file.
3. The commits will be applied one by one in the desired order, stopping if there are any issues with applying the commits and guiding you through resolving the issues.